# How can i create random rectangles (automatically)?

Tags: matlab, random, rectangles

I want to create many rectangles. This should be done automatically. How can I do this without typing thousands of values in my code? Is there an solution?

- In my code I wrote every single coordinate point (4 points of each rectangle) manually in my vector "V".
- Also how to connect them. "F"
- And the value of each rectangle. "C"

My code is

```
clc
clear all
figure;
V = [0,0;1,0;1,1;0,1;5,5;10,5;10,10;5,10;2,2;4,2;4,4;2,4];
F = [1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12];%Dieser Vektor sagt mir in welcher Reihenfolge die Punkte
C = [50;24;99];

patch('Faces',F,'Vertices',V,'FaceVertexCData',C,'FaceColor','flat','EdgeColor','none') %Befehl fürs "zeichnen"
colormap(parula)
colorbar
```

Comment: Just sample **4 random-values**. 1. top-left corner-point ```x```. 2. top-left corner-point ```y```. 3. ```x-length```. 3. ```y-length```. You just need to do some bounds-checking. (e.g. ```x0>=0```, ```y0>=0```; ```x0 + x-length <= width``` and so on)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to create a random rectangle, by randomly generating an (x, y) position for the bottom left corner, and randomly generating a width and height -

```
function rect = createRandomRectangle(maxX, maxY, minHeight, maxHeight, minWidth, maxWidth)

    bottom = maxY * rand;
    left   = maxX * rand;

    height = minHeight + rand * (maxHeight - minHeight);
    width  = minWidth  + rand * (maxWidth  - minWidth);

    rect = [
        left, bottom
        left, bottom + height
        left + width, bottom + height
        left + width, bottom
    ];

end
```

Then you just need to take care of creating your `V`, `F`, `C` matrices (by calling `createRandomRectangle` in a loop) and plotting them.